# Get column values separated by semi colon

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in plsql

tblStudent:-

```
StudentId            Name  .........
1                    A
2                    B
```

tblDept:-

```
DeptId              DeptName       StudentId
1                   Dep Aero         1
2                   IT               1
3                   Dep Maths        1
4                   Dep Chemistry    2
```

I want to get studentId, with all its departments which starts with 'Dep' separated by semi colon, If i pass where StudentId = 1 in SELECT result should look like

```
StudentId         DeptName
  1               Dep Aero;Dep Maths
```

any help please?

Comment: No, I want to get only those departments whose name starts with Dep, so IT won't be there

Comment: What do you want to see if the student doesn't have any matching departments? No data at all, or an empty list?

Comment: empty list will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an empty list of departments when a student has no entries then you can use an outer join between the two tables, e.g.:

```
select s.studentid,
 listagg(d.deptname, ';') within group (order by d.deptname) as deptnames
from tblstudent s
left join tbldept d on d.studentid = s.studentid
and deptname  like 'Dep%'
group by s.studentid;
```

Demo using CTEs for your sample data, including a third student ID with no matching departments:

```
-- CTEs for sample data
with tblstudent (studentid, name) as (
            select 1, 'A' from dual
  union all select 2, 'B' from dual
  union all select 3, 'C' from dual
),
tbldept (deptid, deptname, studentid) as (
            select 1, 'Dep Aero', 1 from dual
  union all select 2, 'IT', 1 from dual
  union all select 3, 'Dep Maths', 1 from dual
  union all select 4, 'Dep Chemistry', 2 from dual
)
-- actual query
select s.studentid,
 listagg(d.deptname, ';') within group (order by d.deptname) as deptnames
from tblstudent s
left join tbldept d on d.studentid = s.studentid
and deptname  like 'Dep%'
group by s.studentid;

 STUDENTID DEPTNAMES                     
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Dep Aero;Dep Maths            
         2 Dep Chemistry                 
         3
```

Your data model looks odd though; you should probably have a department table which only has the department IDs and names, and then another tables that links each student to all of their departments - something like (in CTE form again):

```
-- CTEs for sample data
with tblstudent (studentid, name) as (
            select 1, 'A' from dual
  union all select 2, 'B' from dual
  union all select 3, 'C' from dual
),
tbldept (deptid, deptname) as (
            select 1, 'Dep Aero' from dual
  union all select 2, 'IT' from dual
  union all select 3, 'Dep Maths' from dual
  union all select 4, 'Dep Chemistry' from dual
),
tblstudentdept (studentid, deptid) as (
  select 1, 1 from dual
  union all select 1, 2 from dual
  union all select 1, 3 from dual
  union all select 2, 4 from dual
)
-- actual query
select s.studentid,
 listagg(d.deptname, ';') within group (order by d.deptname) as deptnames
from tblstudent s
left join tblstudentdept sd on sd.studentid = s.studentid
left join tbldept d on d.deptid = sd.deptid
and deptname  like 'Dep%'
group by s.studentid;

 STUDENTID DEPTNAMES                     
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Dep Aero;Dep Maths            
         2 Dep Chemistry                 
         3
```

Either way, if you only want to see a single student's results when add that as a `where` clause, right before the `group by`:

```
...
where s.studentid = 1
group by s.studentid;
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use `LISTAGG` to concat and `LIKE` to filter the records.

```
SELECT studentid,
       LISTAGG(deptname,';') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY deptid
       ) as deptname
FROM t
WHERE deptname LIKE 'Dep%'
GROUP BY studentid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this GROUP_CONCAT -

```
SELECT stud2.studentId,
CAST((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(dep.depName,'; ') FROM  tblDept dep 
INNER JOIN tblStudent stud ON (stud.DeptId = dep.DeptId)))
FROM tblStudent stud2
```

Comment: your query is giving missing right parenthesis error, added ) after dept.depName, ';', still it is giving missing keyword error

Comment: `group_concat()` isn't available in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

you can alo use this:

```
select 
   st.studentid,
   listagg(d.DeptName,';') within group( order by d.DeptName ) 
From tblStudent st
join tblDept d on d.studentid = st.studentid
where DeptName  like 'Dep%'
group by st.studentid
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7df67/5)

Comment: This would get the same result as @Kaushik's query just against `tblDept`; but if you made it a left outer join then it would include students with no matching departments, which might be useful?

Comment: @AlexPoole no. your solution doesnt work. because we have where clause on deptName. Kaushik's query is better. because it hasnt join.

Comment: Keeping the `where` clause would turn it back into an inner join, yes; but you can just move that into the `on` clause instead. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17c89e/4). No idea which result the OP would want though...

Answer (score 0):

No `join` is necessary for your query.  If you want to do this for a particular student id:

```
select listagg(d.DeptName, ';') within group (order by d.DeptName) 
from tblDept d 
where d.studentid = :studentid and
      d.DeptName like 'Dep%';
```